# DBA privileges information

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions

My colleague having DBA ROLE has created a user for me with the following role. `CONNECT`,`DBA`,`RESOURCE` from his own user.

Then I login and check the detail by using the below query.

```
select * from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee = 'MURAHMAN';
```

It's fine and retrieve all the above three roles, but when I query the
table `dba_tab_privs`.

```
select distinct grantee as "User_Name" from dba_tab_privs;
```

This does not retrieve my user.

Then I run the below query.

```
SELECT distinct username, account_status,privilege,owner
 FROM dba_users 
   left outer join dba_tab_privs 
   on (dba_users.username = dba_tab_privs.grantee) 
where dba_users.account_status = 'OPEN';
```

I saw the privilege column against my user is `null`? So, could you please help to find the privilege information against each user? Also please explain why the privilege column is `null` against my user? All other user have the privilege information.

Answer (score 3):

The DBA role includes system privileges (like `SELECT ANY TABLE`), not object privileges.

Comment: Dear Balazs thank you, So could you please tell me how to retrieve the system and object privileges of all DB users?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can get the privs you need with queries like these:

```
select privilege, admin_option from dba_sys_privs
where grantee='USERNAME';
```

and

```
select granted_role, admin_option from dba_role_privs
where grantee='USERNAME';
```

and

```
select owner, table_name, grantor, privilege from dba_tab_privs
where grantee='USERNAME';
```

and for privs granted through roles:

```
select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege from dba_tab_privs
where grantee in 
  (select granted_role from dba_role_privs
   where grantee='USERNAME')
order by 2,3;
```

and for privs on an object:

```
select owner, grantee, grantor, privilege from dba_tab_privs a, dba_roles b 
where a.grantee=b.role and 
table_name='OBJECT'
order by 1,2;
```

Comment: Thank you, It means i don't have object privileges.

Answer (score 0):

*_TAB_PRIVS, *_SYS_PRIVS, and *_ROLE_PRIVS shows *direct* grants.  But if you have inherited a priv via a role (or via a role, granted to a role, granted to a role ....) you need to dig deeper.  There is a classic script for this, written by Pete Finnigan.  http://www.petefinnigan.com/find_all_privs.sql

Comment: I need the information in this format:                                                             UserName|AccountStatus|OWNER|PRIVILIEGE|ROLE.   The Privilege is  System And Object Privilege:

Comment: That's an over-simplified format for what is a complex relationship.  Sys privs don't have owners. A given priv may be granted directly, not through a role. Or it may come through a role that was granted to a role that was granted to a role that was granted to a role that was granted to the user. If you want to know everyone that has a _particular_ priv, go back to Pete Finnigan's site and look for the 'who_has' script.